# Angular Bootstrap UI - how to save data from modal directive to controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap UI in my project.

I have a directive 'HelpDirective', which is used in different controllers. That directive calls HelpService which opens a modal and after it is closed the data is supposed to still remain in the controller model.

But it does not work :(

Here is the template:

```
<button type="button"
    class="btn btn-link"
    selectedHelp="selectedHelp"
    help-directive>
<span class="fa fa-question"></span> Help
</button>
```

Here is my directive:

```
service.directive('helpDirective', ['helpService', function (helpService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        selectedHelp : "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var modal = helpService.openHelpModal(scope.selectedHelp);

             modal.result.then(function (selectedHelp) {
                 console.log(selectedHelp);
                 scope.selectedHelp = selectedHelp;
            });

        });
    }
};
}]);
```

console.log - gives me the right data. But in controller the data is lost.

Comment: try to use selected-help="selectedHelp"

Comment: Can you show your service.js

Comment: Did you use primitives as data model in your modal? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767304/ng-bind-not-updating-after-closing-modal-form/34767624#34767624